# Dropdown menu moves with whole page scroll

Tags: reactjs

I am using the react-select package for our menu dropdowns. However, I've noticed that if a dropdown menu is open and you scroll the page down or up, the menu moves with the page. Expected behavior is that the dropdowns position should stay static. This expected behavior can be seen [here](https://react-select.com/home) on the "single" dropdown. Any ideas what could cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

wrap react-select inside the container with some height & relative position.

Comment: Doesn't look like that fixed the positioning. I did notice that when I hover over the dropdown menu, it snaps it back to the correct position till I scroll again.